# duvida no arquivo kv do kivy

Tags: python, kivy

estou com uma duvida em uma tag no arquivo kv que não consigo entender sua função

```
<TableData>:
rgrid: rgrid
bar_width: 25
scroll_type: ['bars']
bar_color: [0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 1]
bar_inactive_color: [0.2, 0.7, 0.9, .5]
do_scroll_x: True
do_scroll_y: True
effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
viewclass: "ScrollCell"
RecycleGridLayout:
    id: rgrid
    rows: root.nrows
    cols: root.ncols
    size_hint: (None, None)
    width: self.minimum_width
    height: self.minimum_height
    col_default_width: 400
    row_default_height: 60
```

Como funciona esse rgrid? porque ele faz esse 'rgrid:rgrid' qual o nome dessa funcionalidade?

obrigado!

Comment: Marcelo esse rgrid não é uma funcionalidade do kivy, é um id que foi atribuído ao layout, no entanto eu não consigo explicar a linha rgrid:rigrid.

Comment: Obrigado, realmente me expressei mal. Eu queria saber isso mesmo: por que ele faz esse rgrid:rgrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, primeiro temos que entender para o que serve isso.

O KivyLang tem como propósito facilitar a criação das janelas, então foi criado a questão de `ids` para que possamos **referênciar** os objetos e **acessar** as propriedades dos mesmos mais tarde.

Nesse caso, fica visível que foi necessário referenciar ele em uma varíavel **ObjectProperty** dentro de **TableData** para poder mudar alguma coisa do objeto **RecycleGridLayout** dentro do arquivo python.

Certo, expliquei o porquê foi feito dessa forma, mas o KivyLang nos da a facilidade de não pecisar de fazer isso pois podemos **acessar** todos os **ids** de um Widget da seguinde forma:

`self.ids.rgrid.rows = 10`

**Obs. Esse exemplo funciona desde que o `self` seja a classe `TableData` pois estamos acessando os ids de todas as classes que são filhas dela.**

Ou seja, não precisamos definir essa váriavel que esta no seu arquivo .kv para acessar em outro momento:

```
<TableData>:
    rgrid: rgrid
```

*(Cuidado na hora de mudar isso desse arquivo, pois o código foi escrito desse jeito e utiliza isso em outros lugares provavelmente)*